# TestLink XML-RPC The call to the xml-rpc client failed

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xml-rpc, testlink

I was trying to use the testLink(1.9.14 (Padawan)) xml-rpc in selenium JAVA(testNG) to sync the test result to testlink automatically.
I provided the devkey and url what I used for the webdriverJS test.

```
public static String DEVKEY = "e69035750c91d1775900f4ce16dbcfb5";
public static String URL ="http://computername:80/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php";
```

When I ran the test suite, I always got the error something like:

```
testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIException: The call to the xml-rpc client failed.
    at testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIClient.executeXmlRpcMethod(TestLinkAPIClient.java:1266)
    at testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIClient.execXmlRpcMethodWithCache(TestLinkAPIClient.java:1195)
    at testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIClient.getProjects(TestLinkAPIClient.java:726)
    at testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIHelper.getProjectInfo(TestLinkAPIHelper.java:64)
    at testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIHelper.getProjectID(TestLinkAPIHelper.java:48)
    at testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIClient.reportTestCaseResult(TestLinkAPIClient.java:184)
    at rocket.aldon.almwp.test.reportResult(test.java:19)
    at rocket.aldon.almwp.test.Test1(test.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)
Caused by: org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientException: Failed to parse servers response: Expected methodResponse element, got br
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:177)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:145)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:94)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:44)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:53)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:166)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:157)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:146)
    at testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIClient.executeXmlRpcMethod(TestLinkAPIClient.java:1232)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 7; Expected methodResponse element, got br
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.parser.XmlRpcResponseParser.startElement(XmlRpcResponseParser.java:98)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:175)
    ... 39 more
```

Seems like the XML-RPC connection not works here, from the debug info, I could see the api object has `isConnected = false;`
Could someone had met this and got a solution for it?
The jars I am using:

```
testlink-api-client-2.0.jar
selenium-java-2.52.0.zip
selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar
xmlrpc-common-3.1-sources.jar
xmlrpc-common-3.1.jar
xmlrpc-client-3.1-sources.jar
xmlrpc-client-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
guice-3.0.jar
velocity-dep-1.4.jar
ws-commons-util.1.0.2.jar
```

Can someone help to research? I google for a long time still not get clear way.

Comment: By the way, with the devkey and url, I could build the XML-RPC connection in my webdriverJS test correctly. Not sure why in eclipse failed, jar version issue?

Answer (score 1):

> I have following configuration which is working fine.

**Precondition :**

- Automation API should be enable
- Test Project, Test Plan, Build and test case should be created.
- Manual Pass/Fail should be work

Please **do below changes** and **restart Apache service** :

1. Do change as per given below lines in **config.inc.php**  in **Testlink folder** :

   `$tlCfg->exec_cfg->enable_test_automation = ENABLED;`

   `$tlCfg->api->enabled = TRUE;`
2. In `C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink-1.9.15\lib\api\xmlrpc\v1` folder edit this file **xmlrpc.php** as under:

   `require_once("xmlrpc.class.php");`

   `define('XMLRPC_REQUEST', true);`

   `// Some browser-embedded clients send cookies. We don't want them.`
   `$_COOKIE = array();`

   `$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] = file_get_contents("php://input");`

   `$XMLRPCServer = new TestlinkXMLRPCServer();`

Note : Just replace above lines If there is any other configurations are available. Do not edit anything else.

3. After restart Apache service, Open Testlink and **Open Test Project** and enable `Test Automation (API keys)` in Project Management
4. Take **API key from User Setting** and use it as `DEV_KEY`

Please let me know if any query.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I will verify this later.